# Custom Font in WP7 silverlight app

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, fonts, expression-blend

I have an issue, I tried to load a custom font in wp7 silverlight app for my buttons, and it worked nicely. This font supports greek language in word, photoshop etc. But in expression blend or in visual studio when i change the content of the button in greek word then the button fontfamily loads in default font. Why is this happening?

Comment: Does it still show the font it should in runtime? Just not in design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as though you aren't loading the font correctly.

What are you actually doing. (Show the code. Don't just describe it.)